# Ubuntu 22.04 Livepatch + HWE generic kernels

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

According to a [blog post](https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-livepatch-gets-even-better-now-supporting-hardware-enablement-kernels), Canonical is supporting livepatching of the Linux 6.2 hardware enablement (HWE) kernels. However, according to the [list of supported kernels for livepatching](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels), only the cloud kernel images (`azure`, `aws`, `gcp`) are currently supported. Is there any timeline for adding support for `generic` and/or `lowlatency` kernels? The original blog post didn't mention anything about limiting support to only the cloud kernels, so I was surprised to find that the `generic` kernel is not listed.

Related:

- [Livepatch -- plans to support official HWE kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395799/livepatch-plans-to-support-official-hwe-kernels)

Comment: The Ubuntu community, your peer users, have no special insight into Ubuntu Pro, which is a proprietary service sold by Canonical Ltd. We have access only to the same public information that you do.

Comment: @user535733 Sure, but I imagine some of my peer users may be more attentive or aware than I am, and it's entirely possible that I simply missed some announcement or discussion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [18-10-2023 (or earlier)](https://web.archive.org/web/20231018132048/https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels), the generic kernel is now [supported](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels).